# Weird utf-8 encoded column issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

We're looking to upgrade our old sql servers so I got a test db on 2019 and started playing with some of the new features.  I loaded up some tables with SSIS packages from a csv file, then I changed the encoding on some columns to Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 and loaded them again.

Then we got a new csv file, and I loaded that into a new db with the Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8 encodings.

I noticed that the new table had 30 million fewer rows yet about 20 gig more storage space than the first two tests, so I ran some queries to try and figure out where the space was going - just a lot of SUM(LEN(XYZ)) statements trying to figure out which columns were chewing up the most space.

But when I ran these queries on my first utf-8 encoded table, I was getting

```
Invalid data for UTF8-encoded characters
```

errors, which I found very puzzling.  Process of elimination, I found which column was causing the errors.  Then process of elimination the other direction I figured out which was the first row throwing such an error.

It was my **LastName** column and row 2377801.

When I just SELECT * from that row, every column comes back clean and there are no characters that appear anything but 7-bit ASCII.

But when I add LEN(LastName) to the query I get the Invalid data error which is even more puzzling.

I tried googling a lot of permutations around that error and this condition but got zero results.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: To see what's actually stored, find the page with `select sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(%%physloc%%) file_page_slot, *
from T where id = 2377801` Dump the page with DBCC PAGE.

Comment: Which build number of SQL Server 2019 are you on `select @@version`?

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  @@version is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4517790) - 15.0.2070.41 (X64) 
 Oct 28 2019 19:56:59 
 Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: David - I tried your DBCC PAGE suggestion and there were a couple of interesting things.  First, putting your sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter() call in my original query made the LEN(LastName) function succeed.  i.e. the whole query worked when the sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter was in there and it blew up the same way as the original post when it was not.  Second, the old table I was looking at has PAGE compression enabled.  I'd forgotten I'd done that.  But looking at the hex dump, there doesn't seem to be anything non-ascii about the data.

Comment: Does the value look correct on the page?  You can post the hex values and the string representation in your question if you're not sure. Is the column present in any non-clustered indexes?

Comment: The value does look correct on the page.  It's a Chinese name, expressed in ascii-7 characters.  The table is a heap - no indexes at all.

Comment: I added the sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter() call to the query (to get beyond the LEN() exception) and DATALENGTH(LastName) too.  Both DATALENGTH and LEN come out 5 for that row, furthering the impression that LastName on that row is really ascii-7.  It's looking like a weird bug in Sql Server